# 組み込み Linux で ext4 でフォーマットされたSDカードのチェック方法はありますか？

Tags: linux, filesystems

組み込みLinuxで開発を行っています。
Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 1.5.1ベースです。

SDカードにデータを保存していたのですが、SDカードが破損している疑いがあります。
SDカード自体はEXT4でフォーマットしています。
これを確認するため、fsckコマンドを使用したのですが、

```
fsck (busybox 1.21.1, 2015-04-02 16:39:57 JST)
fsck: fsck.auto: No such file or directory
```

というメッセージを表示し、fsckが起動しません。

```
/sbin/fsck
```

は存在しています。
SDカードは、`/media/mmcblk1p1`にマウントしています。

```
~# umount  /media/mmcblk1p1
~# fsck /media/mmcblk1p1
fsck (busybox 1.21.1, 2015-04-02 16:39:57 JST)
fsck: fsck.auto: No such file or directory
~# fsck /dev/mmcblk1p1
fsck (busybox 1.21.1, 2015-04-02 16:39:57 JST)
fsck: fsck.auto: No such file or directory
~# fsck /dev/SD
fsck (busybox 1.21.1, 2015-04-02 16:39:57 JST)
fsck: fsck.auto: No such file or directory
```

等、色々やってみましたが、ダメでした。

何か、良い対処方法が無いでしょうか？
もしくは、fsck以外のファイルシステムのチェック及び修復が無いでしょうか？

---

> ファイルシステムのタイプを明示的に指定するとどうなりますか？

```
~# fsck -t ext4
fsck (busybox 1.21.1, 2015-04-02 16:39:57 JST)
:~# fsck -t ext4 /media/mmcblk1p1
fsck (busybox 1.21.1, 2015-04-02 16:39:57 JST)
fsck: fsck.ext4: No such file or directory
```

という感じでダメでした。

> /sbin/fsck.ext4は存在していますか？

```
:~# /sbin/fsck.ext4
-sh: /sbin/fsck.ext4: No such file or directory
```

ファイルが存在しない様です。

> util-linux-fsckのパッケージをインストールすることは問題を解決すると思います。

組込Linuxにパッケージをインストールする方法をお教え願えないでしょうか？

Comment: ファイルシステムのタイプを明示的に指定するとどうなりますか？ `fsck -t ext4 ...`

Comment: Pokyは使ったことがありませんが、`/sbin/fsck.ext4`は存在していますか？

Comment: `util-linux-fsck`のパッケージをインストールすることは問題を解決すると思います。

Comment: そのSDカードを別のLinux PCのカードリーダーに挿すほうがよいのでは